# Por que a versão reduzida do código SHA1 do git tem 7 caracteres por padrão?

Tags: git, sha1

Estou estudando **Git** e me deparei com o comando `cherry-pick`, que recupera um *commit* específico. O parâmetro passado para esse comando é o código *hash* gerado para identificar unicamente aquele *commit*. Porém, nos exemplos da documentação, é utilizada uma versão reduzida desse *hash*, com apenas 7 caracteres.

Exemplos:

```
git cherry-pick ae33630
```

Esse exemplo acima é a versão reduzida do hash completo, que seria: `ae33630626ac157ea7573233114b560d93f509e0`

Dessa forma, gostaria de saber qual o motivo do **Git** aceitar como parâmetro uma versão reduzida do *hash* e por que especificamente serem 7 caracteres.

Além disso, surge mais uma dúvida: sendo uma versão reduzida, não poderiam acontecer colisões de *hashs* diferentes que iniciam com os mesmos caracteres?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O Git contêm uma infinidade de comandos e fluxos de trabalho do dia-a-dia que você utiliza para gerenciar ou manter o controle de código-fonte de um repositório Git. Com tais comando você será capaz de realizar tarefas básicas de rastreamento e comprometimento de arquivos.

Além de tudo isso o Git contêm [ferramentas para seleção de revisão](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Short-SHA-1), onde você será capaz de explorar uma série de coisas muito poderosas que a Git pode fazer. Não são ferramentas que usará necessariamente no dia-a-dia, mas que você pode precisar em algum momento. E uma delas é o ***Short SHA-1***.

Refente a pergunta: **Não poderiam acontecer colisões de hashs diferentes que iniciam com os mesmos caracteres?**

O Git é inteligente o suficiente para descobrir o que você pretende digitar se você fornecer os primeiros caracteres da *hash*, **desde que seu *SHA-1* parcial tenha pelo menos quatro caracteres e não seja ambíguo**, ou seja, apenas uma *hash* no repositório atual que comece com o *SHA-1* parcial.

O Git pode descobrir uma abreviatura curta e única para seus valores *SHA-1* através do comando `--abbrev-commit` para o comando `git log`. A saída será *hash* mais curtos, mas únicos. O padrão do Git usa **sete caracteres**, mas podem ser mais longos ou curtos, se necessário, desde que seja mantido o *SHA-1* inequívoco e, geralmente, oito a dez caracteres são mais do que suficientes para serem únicos dentro de um projeto. Por exemplo:

```
$ git log --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline
ca82a6d changed the version number
085bb3b removed unnecessary test code
a11bef0 first commit
```

Obs.: O comando `--abbrev-commit` faz com que, ao invés de mostrar o *hash* completo de confirmação hexadecimal de 40 bytes, mostre apenas um prefixo parcial. O número padrão de dígitos pode ser especificado com `--abbrev = <n>` (que também modifica a saída do `diff`, se é exibido). Acrescente `--pretty = oneline` para a saída da informação se tronar muito mais legível para pessoas que usam terminais de 80 colunas.

Mas como eu faço para obter facilmente o SHA curto ou completo para qualquer *commit* no histórico do seu ramo atual, útil para reverter e compartilhar estados de código específicos com outros.

Você pode utilizar o comando: `git rev-list --max-count=1 --abbrev-commit --skip=#` e ganhar câimbras no dedos, OU instalar o [Githash](https://gist.github.com/Ultrabenosaurus/6f499d25cb6d8f9e2256)

Explicação do comando

- `rev-list`: obter *SHA* para qualquer *commit* no histórico do seu ramo atual
- `--max-count=n`: Limita o número de `commits` na saída.
- `--skip=n`: O número de falha confirma antes de começar a mostrar a saída de confirmação.

Comment: Não pude entender com clareza o que significaria um "número de falha", a partir da definição acima. De qualquer forma, sugiro, aqui, a documentação [traduzida] do site oficial sobre a opção [skip](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/pt_BR#git-log---skipltquantidadegt).